# Flexbox "flex: 1" not centring correctly and "flex-grow" pushes up other content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout below and I am trying to centre everything, I am using a pseudo element on my `container` div so that the `innerInputContainer` div can flex grow and fill the remaining space below, that is why the border around the text "Example" goes to the very bottom.

However, my problem is that when I am using this pseudo element and `flex: 1` on my `container` and `innerInputContainer`, it does not centre correctly, it is off by around 50 pixels or so... But if I change `container` and `innerInputContainer` to use `flex-grow: 1` everything is then perfectly centre but when content is dynamically added to `.input`, everything gets pushed up instead of using the available space within `.input`.

[image]

I want everything to be perfectly centrered but also for `.input` not to push everything up when content gets added, when I use `flex: 1` it works but everything is not centre but it does make content that is added to `.input` use the remaining space, switching to `flex-grow: 1` centres everything correctly but does not allow me to add extra content to `.input` without pushing up the rest of the page, even though there is space inside of `.input` to use because `.input` fills the remaining height.

Here is my working example:

```css
*
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.container::before
{
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}

#desc
{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#innerInputContainer
{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.input
{
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.input p
{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="desc">
  
    <p>Text Sample</p>
    
    <p>Text Sample</p>
    
    <p>Text Sample</p>
  
  </div>
  
  <div id="innerInputContainer">
  
    <div class="input">
    
      <p>Example Example Example</p>
    
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: overflow:auto to innerInputContainer ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it and it didn't work, it just added scroll bars and the content still pushed everything up again